# How safe is it to use EXPORT in bash scripts when using GNU Parallel?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, gnu-parallel

How safe is it to use `export` in bash scripts when using GNU Parallel?

I have a parent script.
parent.sh

```
(echo child.sh & echo child_two.sh) || parallel bash

wait
if [[ "$STATUS1" == "0" && "$STATUS2" == "0" ]];
then
    //continue
else
    //stop the process
fi
```

child.sh

Getting the `STATUS1` based on another process

```
export STATUS1
```

child_two.sh

Getting the STATUS2 based on another process

```
export STATUS2
```

Is is safe to use `export` and does the value of `STATUS1` & `STATUS2` get resrt eveytime it is being run?

Comment: @roaima yes its export.

Comment: @roaima This is just a sample code to get a better understand regarding my scenario. Actual case also similar to this but little bix complex. i need to execute both child.sh from parent.sh and need to get the execution state of the child processes. Based on that i need to execute another few files.

Comment: @roaima Nothing is being passed to `parallel` in the code as there is no pipe, only a conditional.

Comment: @roaima Well, it's likely that this is a typo in the pseudo-code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will benefit from looking into `parset` https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html

```
$ parset myvar 'echo do stuff with {};(exit {}); echo $?' ::: 0 0 1 2 3 0 0
$ echo "${myvar[3]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Environments variables are passed into the child processes, not the other way.

If you want to transmit information to the parent process, then you want to put this data into one file per child and `cat` those files after the child processes have ended.

```
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
child.sh $tmp/file & child_two.sh $tmp/file_two
wait 
cat $tmp/* 
rm $tmp -rf
```

If you want to make some optimization, feel free to use a higher level language.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because `export` is setting a variable in a process that is about to be discarded; the parent can never see it.

However, assuming you're using bash, you also don't need to:

```
child.sh &
child_two.sh &

wait -n
STATUS1=$?
wait -n
STATUS2=$?
```

The `wait -n` returns the exit status from *one* of the processes, and repeating it gets the status from the *other*.

The only gotcha with this recipe is that there's no way to know which status came from which process (if you need that read up on bash Job Control).